# SharePoint Folder name and item count in SharePoint Folder in Event Receiver SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I have few SharePoint Folders under Document library(not SharePoint List) in SharePoint 2013.

When i added document(Event Receiver) in SharePoint folder, i require few values called SharePoint Folder Name, and document count in the SharePoint Folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following :

```
SPFolder f = properties.Web.GetFile(properties.AfterUrl).ParentFolder;
string foldername = f.Name;

To get the count of items in the folder:
SPQuery query = new SPQuery() ;
    query.Folder = f;

    SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query) ;
int count = items.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Solution:

```
SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
SPFile file = item.File;
//To get folder name
string fldrname = file.ParentFolder.ToString();
SPList list = properties.List;
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

//Hard coded the folder name, but you can get the value(substring Of file variable)from file variable.
query.Folder = list.RootFolder.SubFolders["Testing1"];

//Recursive Scope....
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
SPListItemCollection allitems = list.GetItems(query);
int filecount = allitems.Count;
```

Cheers:)